# Destroy singleTask Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app I have an activity A which launches in singleTask mode and now I want to reinitialize/reopen this activity with intent sent from one of my services. Any suggestions/solutions on how to do it?

I already tried

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
```

but its not working

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"? what do you expect to happen? and what is actually happens?

Comment: I am using Socket service which sends the intent and as the activity is singleTask its retriving the previous state  but I want to reinitialize it. Basically, I want to detach the already created activity.

Comment: just use finish() before you start new one.

Comment: in the service?

Comment: no, use broadcastreciever in your activity and sendbrocast in your service

Comment: So the use case here is while I am inside activity A, socketService can send  intent to reinitailize the activity A.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147244/discussion-between-mehran-zamani-and-mayank-singhal).

Comment: post your manifest please.